# 13+ wire DB-25 or DB-15 cable

Tags: cables, wire, cable-assemblies

I can't find an answer to this anywhere so I thought I'd ask around here.

I need a cable with 13 or more wires in it, preferably with a DB-15 or DB-25 connector, but I can't find one anywhere.  I grabbed some DB-25 serial cables but they only had 6 wires in them (not all pins are used), and I can't find a reliable way to discover how various cables are wired before I cut them in half and find out myself.

Anyone know a cheap source for 13+ wire cables?  Preferably thin and black.  I can also just get the cable and wire up D-sub terminals, but I wouldn't know where to start to look for this...

Any help or resources would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How about ribbon cable in DB25 connectors? http://search.digikey.com/us/en/cat/cable-assemblies/d-sub/1573638?k=db25%20ribbon

Comment: Would do it in most circumstances but this is for a video game controller... ribbon is too ugly.  I think this should work http://www.amazon.com/Belkin-Straight-Thru-Serial-DB25M/dp/B00004Z5MT/ref=sr_1_7?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1333908092&sr=1-7

Comment: You should be able to get connectors and bulk cable from most electronic distributors (DigiKey, Mouser, Farnell...) so you could make your own cable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DB-25 cable with only 6 wires is probably configured as a nullmodem. Try to find a straight EIA-232 cable for connection between DCE (Data Communication Equipment, i.e. modem) and DTE (Data Terminal Equipment, aka PC), this should have all 25 pins connected.

A DB-15 VGA cable should also give you 13 wires, but return ground for red, blue and green may share the same wire (they shouldn't).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look around.  As far as I can tell most VGA cables I find are 12 wires: 8 signal + ground, and 3 RGB.  Also, I need 13 wires with small diameter....

Comment: Also if you take a look at the cables I bought here, it seems to be a DCE to DTE, no?  There's just something I'm not getting here.  http://www.techforless.com/cgi-bin/tech4less/PCSERIAL-10?mv_pc=google_base&tts=20120408023701&utm_source=google_shopping&utm_medium=free&utm_campaign=google_shopping

Comment: @granto - not clear from the description on the site. Anyway, a nullmodem cable is for connecting DTE to DTE (PC to PC).

Answer (score 0):

Most legacy [parallel printer cables](http://pinouts.ru/ParallelPorts/ParallelPC_pinout.shtml) should have 13+ conductors.

The PC type will traditionally have a *DB-25* male connector on one end and a Centronics male on the other end.

A *DB-15* connector is not what most people will think.  Most are thinking of a [DA-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature) connector.